# How to review a report embedded in a form in print preview format

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to know how to ensure that a report that I have embedded in a form is updated as the form opens so that in print preview mode, the report is fresh. In particularly, I am using this report to show bar graphs which I have created using rectangle shapes which change according to the values in the fields coming from the table bound to the report.  Unfortunately, although I have the default view of the embedded report set to print preview and the code to change the rectangle lenghts set on the 'On format' event, the code does not update the report.  Perhaps the on format event needs to be triggered in some other way.  Below is my code.  Thanks

```
Private Sub Corpo_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)

Dim sngLunghezza As Single

    sngLunghezza = retTotale.Width * txtMedia / 100
    retPercentuale.Width = sngLunghezza

  If txtMedia < 50 Then
             retPercentuale.BackColor = vbRed

    Else
        retPercentuale.BackColor = vbGreen

  End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I can offer is: I think the event you've written your code in isn't getting triggered and one suggestion might be to put your code the the report's open or load event.

Comment: No that doesn't work because each record then gets formatted as if the value represented by 'txtMedia' is the same for all, showing bar graphs identical for all records.  I need the value 'txtMedia' to be different for each record creating a bar graph with a different length for each individual record.  Strangely, in print preview the report is good when running the report alone (OUTSIDE OF THE FORM). The problem occurs only once the report is embedded within the form.